# Google place autocomplete by classname not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Hi i have a textbox and on focus it autocomplete place,street, name  this work for me if i select by `id` , but later i have many dynamic textbox control so for that i have fixed classname, same code not working if i select by `classname`

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9vhKr/2/)**

**Code:**

```
 getPlace();
 getPlace_dynamic();

     function getPlace() {
         var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
         new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
         var input = document.getElementById('Destination');
         // var input = document.getElementsByClassName('destination');
         var options = {
             bounds: defaultBounds,
             types: ['establishment']
         };
         autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     }

     function getPlace_dynamic() {
         var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
         new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

         var input = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
         var options = {
             bounds: defaultBounds,
             types: ['establishment']
         };
         autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     }
```

---

```
<input id="Destination" tabindex="1" class="txt_box" type="text" />
</br>
</br>Later Dynamically generated
<input tabindex="1" class="myClass" type="text" />
<input tabindex="1" class="myClass" type="text" />
```

Comment: Try to change this line `var input = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');` to `getElementById` and provide some specific `ID`s for your second and third inputs

Comment: @Pavlo: by id is working, i need to select by classname as it generated dynamicaly from third party

Comment: Then Praveen's answer should resolve your issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')
```

returns an array of elements with that className(`myClass`).

So what you need to do is to *iterate* each element and assign it to Google autocomplete api like below

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i], options);
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/9vhKr/3/)

Comment: @Praveen Good one. Very helpful. Thanks

Comment: YOUR SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK ON JSFIDDLE, PLEASE UPDATE.